# Select values from different columns based on a variable containing column names

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table like this:

```
col1   col2   col3  new  
1       4     55    col1 
2       3     44    col2
3       34    35    col2
4       44    87    col3
```

I want to populate another column `matched_value` that contains the values from the respective column names given in the `new` column:

```
col1   col2   col3  new    matched_value
1       4     55    col1        1
2       3     44    col2        3
3       34    35    col2        34
4       44    87    col3        87
```

E.g., in the first row, the value of `new` is "col1" so `matched_value` takes the value from `col1`, which is 1.

How can I do this efficiently in R on a very large data.table?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An excuse to use the obscure `.BY`:

```
DT[, newval := .SD[[.BY[[1]]]], by=new]

   col1 col2 col3  new newval
1:    1    4   55 col1      1
2:    2    3   44 col2      3
3:    3   34   35 col2     34
4:    4   44   87 col3     87
```

*How it works.* This splits the data into groups based on the strings in `new`. The value of the string for each group is stored in `newname = .BY[[1]]`. We use this string to select the corresponding column of `.SD` via `.SD[[newname]]`. `.SD` stands for **S**ubset of **D**ata.

*Alternatives.* `get(.BY[[1]])` should work just as well in place of `.SD[[.BY[[1]]]]`. According to a benchmark run by @David, the two ways are equally fast.

Comment: lovely. very fast Looks like some other language. how does it work? waiting for the explanation! thanks!

Comment: +1 as this solution is faster than my `dt[, matched_value := as.integer(get(new)), by=1:nrow(dt)]` solution.

Comment: @user3664020 Finished adding an explanation. Let me know if it's not clear. I know the code looks bizarre.

Comment: @David I think `get` might be just as fast (maybe faster?) if you did `get(.BY[[1]]), by=new`

Comment: @Frank for curiosity's sake I've tested both `get(.BY[[1]])` and `.SD[[.BY[[1]]]]` using `system.time` on 10^6 rows. The two are indistinguishable in time.

Comment: @David Thanks for looking into it; that's interesting and useful to know. I've added a note to the answer.

Comment: @Frank Just a note that in 2020, `.SD[[.BY[[1]]]]` no longer seems to work with a message indicating that `.SD` cannot be found. Luckily, `get(.BY[[1]])` continues to work!

Answer (score 2):

We can `match` the 'new' column with the column names of the dataset to get the column index, `cbind` with the row index (`1:nrow(df1)`) and extract the corresponding elements of the dataset based on row/column index.  It can be assigned to a new column.

```
df1$matched_value <- df1[-4][cbind(1:nrow(df1),match(df1$new, colnames(df1) ))]
df1
#  col1 col2 col3  new matched_value
#1    1    4   55 col1             1
#2    2    3   44 col2             3
#3    3   34   35 col2            34
#4    4   44   87 col3            87
```

NOTE: If the OP have a `data.table`, one option is convert to `data.frame` or use `with=FALSE` while subsetting.

```
 setDF(df1) #to convert to 'data.frame'.
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(45)
df2 <- data.frame(col1= sample(1:9, 20e6, replace=TRUE),
col2= sample(1:20, 20e6, replace=TRUE), 
col3= sample(1:40, 20e6, replace=TRUE),
col4=sample(1:30, 20e6, replace=TRUE),
new= sample(paste0('col', 1:4), 20e6, replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
system.time(df2$matched_value <- df2[-5][cbind(1:nrow(df2),match(df2$new, colnames(df2) ))])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  2.54    0.37    2.92
```

Comment: Can you please a give an equivalent data table syntax? Also, would it be fast? I have a very big dataset having around 20 million rows.

Comment: @user3664020  The row/column indexing is fast, but `cbind`ing could be a bottleneck.  How many columns you have?

Comment: 5 columns. And it is data table.

Comment: Maybe using `fastmatch` ?

Comment: @akrun could you please give an equivalent data table syntax? I am getting an error while applying it on a data table.

Comment: @user3644020 It is because of the indexing that is `df1[-1]` may not work, use `df1[, -4, with=FALSE]`

Comment: @user3664020  Check if this is fast `df1[, matched_value := melt(df1, id.var='new')[new==variable]$value]`

Comment: @akrun it is fast, but it is not picking up correct values, not sure where the values are coming from in the `matched_value` column....

Comment: @user3664020  In the example, it was giving the right output, didn't test it carefully.

Comment: @akrun melt output is getting sorted from col1 to col4, i,e why i am getting wrong values. How do I prevent sorting?

Comment: @user3664020 Based on the dataset you have, the base R method is pretty fast, done within 2 secs.

Comment: presumably `new` is a factor, so really all you need is `transform(dat, val=dat[cbind(1:nrow(dat), new)])`