# Merge multiple tables by row and column in R

Tags: r, merge

Let's say I have three tables that overlap.

```
    A   B   C   D
A   12  16  17  14
B   62  66  9   85
C   37  31  59  75
D   74  76  89  25

    A   B   E   F
A   12  16  11  19
B   62  66  57  28
E   24  21  4   51
F   7   1   68  22

    C   D   E   F
C   59  75  77  80
D   89  25  88  30
E   67  87  4   51
F   39  69  68  22
```

I would like to combine them by row and by column, without any duplicated rows or columns, and with row and column names intact.

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
A   12  16  17  14  11  19
B   62  66  9   85  57  28
C   37  31  59  75  77  80
D   74  76  89  25  88  30
E   24  21  67  87  4   51
F   7   1   39  69  68  22
```

After three days I managed to cobble this together (with help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823976/merge-data-frames-to-eliminate-missing-observations), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566799/change-variable-name-in-for-loop-using-r), and probably others I've forgotten):

```
#Import tables as dataframes
file.names <- dir(pattern = ".tab")
for(i in 1:length(file.names)){
  nam <- paste("table.", i, sep = "")  #rename the data as table.1 ... table.n
  assign(nam, as.data.frame(as.matrix(read.delim(file.names[i],
         row.names=1, header=TRUE, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE))))
}

#Import an empty file (i.e. just column and row names) 
#that you will fill with your smaller data tables
out.file <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(read.delim("Blank_table.csv",
                                               row.names=1, header=TRUE, sep=",")))

#Create a list of the dataframes
file.names = lapply(ls(pattern = "table.[0-9]"), get)

#Add columns that we can use for merging
#because using 'merge' on dataframes destroys row names
out.file$rows <- rownames(out.file)
for(i in 1:length(file.names)){
  rownams <- rownames(file.names[[i]])
  file.names[i] <- lapply(file.names[i], cbind, rows = rownams)
}

#Combine the tables
for(i in 1:length(file.names)){
  file <- file.names[i]
  out.file <- aggregate(. ~ rows, data = merge(out.file, file, all = TRUE),
                        na.action = na.pass, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

This does what I want, but it takes a long time when I'm merging hundreds of tables. I feel like there is probably a simpler way to do it, but I don't want to spend another three days of trial and error to get there.

What I'm imagining, is something along these lines:

1. Import the empty table *n* times into a list of dataframes
2. Import the data tables and merge one each into an empty dataframe in the list
3. Create a new dataframe that is the mean of the corresponding cells in all the imported dataframes

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: Here are my example tables from `dput`:

```
table.1 <- structure(list(A = c(12L, 62L, 37L, 74L), B = c(16L, 66L, 31L, 
76L), C = c(17L, 9L, 59L, 89L), D = c(14L, 85L, 75L, 25L)), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), row.names = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "data.frame")

table.2 <- structure(list(A = c(12L, 62L, 24L, 7L), B = c(16L, 66L, 21L, 
1L), E = c(11L, 57L, 4L, 68L), F = c(19L, 28L, 51L, 22L)), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "E", "F"), row.names = c("A", "B", "E", "F"), class = "data.frame")

table.3 <- structure(list(C = c(59L, 89L, 67L, 39L), D = c(75L, 25L, 87L, 
69L), E = c(77L, 88L, 4L, 68L), F = c(80L, 30L, 51L, 24L)), .Names = c("C", 
"D", "E", "F"), row.names = c("C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "data.frame")

out.file <- structure(list(A = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), B = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), C = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), D = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), E = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), F = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), row.names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Please use `dput` to share your data.

Comment: @pableiros No. I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subsetting solution, without additional package (using df1, df2 and df3 as defined by @emehex) :

```
# List of dataframes to combine
DF<-list(df1, df2, df3)

COL<-unique(unlist(lapply(DF, colnames)))
ROW<-unique(unlist(lapply(DF, rownames)))
# Empty DF with all combinations
TOTAL<-matrix(data=NA, nrow=length(ROW), ncol=length(COL), dimnames=list(ROW, COL))
# Subsetting :
for (df in DF) { 
    TOTAL[rownames(df), colnames(df)] <- as.matrix(df)
}
```

Subsetting is faster than merging, with numerous dataframes it may be more efficient (see @aichao answer her : [For each row extract the value in the column name that match another value in the cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020500/for-each-row-extract-the-value-in-the-column-name-that-match-another-value-in-th/39020861#39020861)). You just have to adapt the `DF` list to `file.names` for your code.

Comment: I've run this with the sample data and it looks pretty slick. I'll let you know how it goes with my hundreds of tables of real data.

Comment: With the method I posted previously it took about half an hour to merge 1275 ten-by-ten tables. Your subsetting solution did it in about 1 minute. Fantastic!

Comment: Great ! I'm glad I could help you

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what your .csvs look like so this is the best I can do (with the three example tables above)...

Data Import

```
df1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 
"A   B   C   D
A   12  16  17  14
B   62  66  9   85
C   37  31  59  75
D   74  76  89  25")

df2 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 
"A   B   E   F
A   12  16  11  19
B   62  66  57  28
E   24  21  4   51
F   7   1   68  22")

df3 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 
"C   D   E   F
C   59  75  77  80
D   89  25  88  30
E   67  87  4   51
F   39  69  68  22")
```

Solution with `dplyr`, `tibble` and `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

# intermediate tables for rownames and gathering
df1_c <- df1 %>% 
    rownames_to_column("Name") %>% 
    gather(key, value, -Name)

df2_c <- df2 %>% 
    rownames_to_column("Name") %>% 
    gather(key, value, -Name)

df3_c <- df3 %>% 
    rownames_to_column("Name") %>% 
    gather(key, value, -Name)

# formatted dataframe from spread
df <- bind_rows(df1_c, df2_c, df3_c) %>% 
    group_by(Name, key) %>% 
    distinct(.keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
    spread(key, value)
```

Output

```
df
#    Name     A     B     C     D     E     F
# * <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     A    12    16    17    14    11    19
# 2     B    62    66     9    85    57    28
# 3     C    37    31    59    75    77    80
# 4     D    74    76    89    25    88    30
# 5     E    24    21    67    87     4    51
# 6     F     7     1    39    69    68    22
```