# Fill a dataframe column with values of others according to a specific column

Tags: r, dataframe

My `dataframe` looks like:

[image]

I tried to add a new column and fill it with the value of the column number (intervals + 3) for each row.

For example if `intervals = 3` , I want to get the value of `DF[,3+3]`

I tried this, but it didn't work :

```
DF$new_col <- DF[,DF$intervals[]+3]
```

Comment: So for `intervals == 3`, you want to get the value of the column `solarNoon`?

Comment: `DF$new_col = DF[1:nrow(DF),DF$intervals+3]`

Comment: Please provide your example as plain text (using `dput` for example) instead of pictures. It's easier for SO community to answer and for search engine to be efficient

Comment: @Emmanuel-Lin sorry this is my first post here but I will take your comment into consideration next time

Comment: @LAP yes exactly, the new column will take values from: midnight, sunrise, solarNoon, sunset, night, lastnight columns according to values in "intervals" column.
So if intervals == 3, I want to get the value of solarNoon column
if intervals == 2, I get the value of sunrise, etc.

Comment: You might also be able to create a `data.table` solution (which would probably be very fast) with the help of this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33310179/select-values-from-different-columns-based-on-a-variable-containing-column-names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how fast it is, but here's a solution using `split` and `mapply`.

Some example data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(var1 = 1:10,
                 var2 = 11:20,
                 var3 = 21:30,
                 intervals = sample(0:2, 10, replace = T))

   var1 var2 var3 intervals
1     1   11   21         0
2     2   12   22         1
3     3   13   23         1
4     4   14   24         2
5     5   15   25         0
6     6   16   26         2
7     7   17   27         2
8     8   18   28         1
9     9   19   29         1
10   10   20   30         0
```

We first sort the dataframe by `intervals`:

```
df <- df[order(df$intervals),]

   var1 var2 var3 intervals
1     1   11   21         0
5     5   15   25         0
10   10   20   30         0
2     2   12   22         1
3     3   13   23         1
8     8   18   28         1
9     9   19   29         1
4     4   14   24         2
6     6   16   26         2
7     7   17   27         2
```

Now we `split` the data into subsets for every value of `intervals`.

```
df1 <- split(df, df$intervals)
```

Now we use `mapply` to simultaneously loop over the list of subsets and the vector `unique(df$intervals)+1` (for you it would be +3) to select the right values.

```
newvalues <- mapply(function(x, y){
  x[, y]
}, df1, unique(df$intervals)+1)
```

Finally the feed the values back to the original, sorted dataframe by using `unlist`.

```
df$new <- unlist(newvalues)
```

Result:

```
   var1 var2 var3 intervals new
1     1   11   21         0   1
5     5   15   25         0   5
10   10   20   30         0  10
2     2   12   22         1  12
3     3   13   23         1  13
8     8   18   28         1  18
9     9   19   29         1  19
4     4   14   24         2  24
6     6   16   26         2  26
7     7   17   27         2  27
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the description of the problem is not absolutely clear from the question. Still check the following `for` loop based solution if its solves your query. Please note since no reproducible data was provided, I have generated a dummy data for this purpose.

```
> df<-data.frame(D1=c(2,8,1,5,2),D2=c(7,3,5,6,8),D3=c(9,6,4,1,0),D4=c(12,20,61,80,91),Interval=c(1,2,1,0,1))
> df
  D1 D2 D3 D4 Interval
1  2  7  9 12        1
2  8  3  6 20        2
3  1  5  4 61        1
4  5  6  1 80        0
5  2  8  0 91        1
> for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
+ df[i,6]<-df[i,df$Interval[i]+3]
+ }
> df
  D1 D2 D3 D4 Interval V6
1  2  7  9 12        1 12
2  8  3  6 20        2  2
3  1  5  4 61        1 61
4  5  6  1 80        0  1
5  2  8  0 91        1 91
```

Comment: thank you for your answer it's exactly what i want but as the dataframe is very large I would like to avoid using a for loop .